# How to add fade in fade out for music file

Tags: android, ringtone

I am using ringdroid ringtone cutter library in my music player. I need fade in and fade out for my music player at the start and end. That means volume low at both start and end of the music file. How to do that?

Comment: when starting playback continuoulsy increase the volume, and when the track is about to finish - continuously decrease it.

Comment: Sry, I need to do that in that music file. So I can play that in anywhere. So while saving itself I need to save with fade in.